# list open ajax/http requests via Javascript or JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, http, browser, selenium-webdriver

I'm building a test suite using selenium. I have a need to check what vanilla http requests and what ajax requests are outstanding when a test fails.

Is there a way to query a browser and ask it which requests are still pending and list them? I know that I can get to it using various dev-tools/firebug, but can I get that information from the browser via javascript.

Alternatively/additionally, is there a way to ask that of JQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Browsermob Proxy to log HAR requests. As per documentation it should give you the details of blocked calls etc. There is a good article about what and how to generate them. We use har files and selenium to check if a particular call is made and if we gotten expected response, but i have not done exercise to see if they were blocked. But as per documentation they should have information about blocked calls. If the ajax is not even made, you cannot get them on har files.

http://www.speedawarenessmonth.com/what-is-a-har-file-and-what-do-i-use-it-for/